# Getting pipenv working in a Virtualenv where the App is working

Tags: pip, virtualenv, pipenv

I have my Django App working in a Virtualenv. 
I would like to switch to pipenv. However, pipenv install fails with a dependency error.
Given that the App is working, I guess all the libraries are in the Virtualenv.

When getting the App working through Virtualenv + pip, I had to resolve the library dependency, but was able to and got it working. The thinking behind moving to pipenv is to avoid the dependency issues in a multiple member team setup.

Is there a way to tell pipenv to just take the versions of the libraries in the virtualenv and just go with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `setup.py` file you can install it with `pipenv install .`. Or even better, make it an editable development dependency: `pipenv install -e . --dev`.

You can also create a Pipfile/virtual env from a requirements.txt file. So you could do a pip freeze, then install from the requirements file.

### Freezing your dependencies

From your working app virtual env, export your dependencies to a requirements file.

`pip freeze > frozen-reqs.txt`

Then create a new virtual env with pipenv, and install from the frozen requirements.

`pipenv install -r frozen-reqs.txt`

Then go into the `Pipfile` and start removing everything but the top level dependencies, and re-lock. Also where-ever possible, avoid pinning requirements as this makes dependency resolution much harder.

You can use `pipenv graph` and `pipenv graph --reverse` to help with this.